# How many sims fit in a car?

Tags: simcity-2013

I'm trying to work up a plan for traffic in my city, and I think it's easy enough for me to figure out how many cars can make it through a stopsign unopposed in an hour, and how many cars can make it through a stoplight opposed in an hour... but it's all for naught as I don't know how many workers are in a car.

I know that low wealth, high density residential buildings have 400 workers, 200 shoppers and 100 students.  What I don't know: how many cars does that turn into?

Comment: Depends. Are they clown sims?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One car = one sim.

The majority of your effort should be focused around preventing as many sims from driving as possible through the use of horizontal mixed use zoning that allows for walking to shopping and work and public transportation options.

Comment: So each low wealth high density building dumps 700 cars on the road each day?  I don't believe that.

Comment: Yes it does seem like an absurd number but anyone interested in this can watch the population data grid and see each "worker" or "shopper" count lowered or raised by 1 for a building whenever a car or pedestrian leaves or enters. Walkable cities with low wealth high density are almost required.

Comment: This is why you **never** want low wealth C buildings. 1200 $ jobs to fill == FML.